# is there is a way to automate the redshift vaccum process through udf?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, aws-redshift

I have more that 300+ table in redshift.

Data is getting update daily basic just want to know can i create a udf in redshift  to automate the vaccum process.

I found a link automate using python but not that great python coder i am so looking for solution in sql script.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't use a udf for something like this, udf's are simple input/ouput function meant to be used in queries.

Your best bet is to use this open source tool from AWS Labs: [VaccumAnalyzeUtility](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/tree/master/src/AnalyzeVacuumUtility). The great thing about using this tool is that it is very smart about only running `VACUUM` on tables that need them, and it will also run `ANALYZE` on tables that need it.

It's pretty easy to set up as cron job. Here is an example of how it can be done:

Pull the amazon-redshift-utils repo in git:

```
git clone https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils
cd amazon-redshift-utils
```

Create a script that can be run by cron. In your text editor create a file called `run_vacuum_analyze.sh` with the following, and fill in the values for the your environment:

```
export REDSHIFT_USER=<your db user name>
export REDSHIFT_PASSWORD=<your db password>
export REDSHIFT_DB=<your db>
export REDSHIFT_HOST=<your redshift host>
export REDSHIFT_PORT=<your redshift port>
export WORKSPACE=$PWD/src/AnalyzeVacuumUtility 

#
# VIRTUALENV
#

rm -rf $WORKSPACE/ve1
virtualenv -p python2.6 "$WORKSPACE/ve1"
# enter virutalenv
source $WORKSPACE/ve1/bin/activate

#
# DEPENDENCIES
#
pip install PyGreSQL

cd $WORKSPACE/run

#
# RUN IT
#
python analyze-vacuum-schema.py  --db $REDSHIFT_DB --db-user $REDSHIFT_USER --db-pwd $REDSHIFT_PASSWORD --db-port $REDSHIFT_PORT --db-host $REDSHIFT_HOST
```

Then create a cron job that will run this script (In this example, I run it daily at 2:30 AM)

```
chmod +x run_vacuum_analyze.sh
crontab -e
```

Add the following entry:

```
30 2 * * * <path-to-the-cloned-repo>/run_vacuum_analyze.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for the info ,Can you please share the documents if you have step by step approach.Thanks a lot for your help and support

Comment: Can I create a shell script and run as cron job

vaccum Table1;
vaccum Table2;
vaccum Table3;
vaccum Table4;
.
.
.
.
.
Vaccum TableN;

Answer (score 0):

You CANNOT use a UDF for this, UDFs cannot run command that update data.

Comment: Any other suggestion ,I appreciate your help

Comment: create a long sql script with all your tables?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have created a AWS lamda function in java and used cloud watch event to schedule using a cron. AWS lamda function in java expects shaded jar to be uploaded. I have created environment variable in lamda function for redshift connection properties which are passed into java handler.[image]

Comment: you can download the java shaded java project from here and build using mvn to generate shaded jar. The Main class has a list that takes all table names that needs vacuum and analyze. [link] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iF5i3cBPEJT6hIdCpkmy3C_KruxsoGw7)

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use auto vaccum ,Redshift now providing this option

Answer (score 0):

Here is my shell script utility to automate this with better control over the table filters.

https://thedataguy.in/automate-redshift-vacuum-analyze-using-shell-script-utility/

#### Example Commands:

Run vacuum and Analyze on all the tables.

```
./vacuum-analyze-utility.sh -h endpoint -u bhuvi -d dev
```

Run vacuum and Analyze on the schema sc1, sc2.

```
./vacuum-analyze-utility.sh -h endpoint -u bhuvi -d dev -s 'sc1,sc2'
```

Run vacuum FULL on all the tables in all the schema except the schema sc1. But don’t want Analyze

```
./vacuum-analyze-utility.sh -h endpoint -u bhuvi -d dev -k sc1 -o FULL -a 0 -v 1

or

./vacuum-analyze-utility.sh -h endpoint -u bhuvi -d dev -k sc1 -o FULL -a 0
```

Run Analyze only on all the tables except the tables tb1,tbl3.

```
./vacuum-analyze-utility.sh -h endpoint -u bhuvi -d dev -b 'tbl1,tbl3' -a 1 -v 0

or 

./vacuum-analyze-utility.sh -h endpoint -u bhuvi -d dev -b 'tbl1,tbl3' -v 0
```

Use a password on the command line.

```
./vacuum-analyze-utility.sh -h endpoint -u bhuvi -d dev -P bhuvipassword
```

Run vacuum and analyze on the tables where unsorted rows are greater than 10%.

```
./vacuum-analyze-utility.sh -h endpoint -u bhuvi -d dev -v 1 -a 1 -x 10

or

./vacuum-analyze-utility.sh -h endpoint -u bhuvi -d dev -x 10
```

Run the Analyze on all the tables in schema sc1 where stats_off is greater than 5.

```
./vacuum-analyze-utility.sh -h endpoint -u bhuvi -d dev -v 0 -a 1 -f 5
```

Run the vacuum only on the table tbl1 which is in the schema sc1 with the Vacuum threshold 90%.

```
./vacuum-analyze-utility.sh -h endpoint -u bhuvi -d dev -s sc1 -t tbl1 -a 0 -c 90
```

Run analyze only the schema sc1 but set the analyze_threshold_percent=0.01

```
./vacuum-analyze-utility.sh -h endpoint -u bhuvi -d dev -s sc1 -t tbl1 -a 1 -v 0 -r 0.01
```

Do a dry run (generate SQL queries) for analyze all the tables on the schema sc2.

```
./vacuum-analyze-utility.sh -h endpoint -u bhuvi -d dev -s sc2 -z 1
```